# How to do a screen capture of content on web page/join 2 images

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I have a page where I am using Raphael.js to actually allow user to move a dot around the canvas which has a background image. What I am trying to do is to capture the end image of the canvas where I'll be able to see where the user placed the dot after the user clicks on a 'confirm position' button. I've thought of two methods, however I am not too sure of how to execute them.

Method 1: Just capture the canvas as an image. Somehow this isn't possible with Javascript alone and I'm not too sure if Raphael has a built in function to allow this. I also read about exporting the svg xml file and pass it through the a library like 'Batik' however I'm not exactly sure how to do that. The tutorials I've read are really confusing.

Method 2: To use the coordinates of the dot and overlay a dot image that I already have onto the background image and save it as an image.

Please advice and I hope I've been clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this server-side:

- get the SVG code with JavaScript
- send it to a PHP script on your server with XHR
- have PHP save the SVG to a file and use Inkscape to convert it in one command:
  `inkscape in.svg -e out.png -w 300 -h 500`
- send back the name of the newly created file to the client
- display a link to the picture in JavaScript

This method does not provide VML support (Internet Explorer's vector graphics format); however, you can use [VectorConverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/) to convert VML to SVG.